# How to create Android bluetooth native module in react-native or Is there any plugin readily available

Tags: android, bluetooth, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am working on application which connects to a bluetooth device and gets data from it. As React native allows to create native modules and use them in React JS, I am trying to create a native bluetooth module.
Could any one help me out.

```
/**
* Created by ravitheja.bandari on 4/4/2016.
 */
public class BluetoothRN extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {


// note that webView.isPaused() is not Xwalk compatible, so tracking it     poor-man style
private boolean isPaused;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private Promise bluetoothPromise;

private static final int BLUETOOTH_ENABLE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST = "E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST";
private static final String E_FAILED_TO_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = "E_FAILED_TO_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH";


public BluetoothRN(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
super(reactContext);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
return "BluetoothAndroid";
}



@ReactMethod
public void getAdapter(){
bluetoothAdapter =   BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

@ReactMethod
public void getBondedDevices(final Promise promise){

Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

if (currentActivity == null) {
    promise.reject(E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST, "Activity doesn't exist");
    return;
}

// Store the promise to resolve/reject when picker returns data
bluetoothPromise = promise;

try {
    Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

    currentActivity.startActivityForResult(turnOn, BLUETOOTH_ENABLE_REQUEST);
} catch (Exception e) {
    bluetoothPromise.reject(E_FAILED_TO_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH, e);
    bluetoothPromise = null;
}


}



private ArrayList getPairedDevices(){
pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
    list.add(bt.getName());

return list;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();

return constants;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
}
```

ReactPackage

```
public class BluetoothReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {

List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

modules.add(new BluetoothRN(reactContext));


return modules;
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
return null;
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is, please be more specific. Is something not working? Are you getting an error message? What part of the code isn't doing what you expect (what's the actual vs expected results).

Answer (score 0):

re: Is there any plugin readily available?

I'm searching the same thing and found this one:

React Native version of BluetoothSerial plugin. For both android and ios
https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial